# Using AWS Lambda + API Gateway for generation of vector map tiles - Getting "Malformed Lambda proxy response" error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, vector-tiles

I am using AWS lambda which generates vector tiles. Tiles are being send in format

```
return {
    body: data,
    isBase64Encoded: true,
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
  }
```

My data object is in octet-stream format.

My API Gateway

- is using integration proxy
- response headers has 'Content-Type'
- Content-Type is set for 'application/octet-stream'
- In settings > Binary media type is set - **application/octet-stream**

Functionality of the lambda is expected to work fine. Problem is in sending response back. I am still getting the error

> Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response

Comment: "lambda is expected to work fine" - have you inspected CloudWatch logs for any errors? You have to verify that your function actually works.

Comment: Also your return statement is not a valid python, so I'm not sure this is your actual code?

Comment: - I am using Javacript, not Python

Comment: My expectation about function is that I can see the the CloudWatch logs, and it's everything fine there

Comment: Ah ok. I automatically assumed python when I  saw it. Maybe you can update your tags or something add javascript tag.